# Python-Django -the service of generating random numbers does not stops?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to print the random values upon clicking the `start` button and stop it via clicking `stop` button. The `Start` button works as expected , ie prints the random values upon clicking but when `stop` button is clicked, it does not breaks out of the loop(though it enters the `stop` section) and keeps printing the random values. How can I stop printing random values and start it again.??

A brief summary of my code:- In views.py, the `signal` variable is requested which is then send to the `generate_random_temperature` function which generates random numbers. Generating of numbers works fine, but it is not able to stop the service of generating the numbers.

How can I stop it?

**HTML file**

```
    <form type = "POST">
        {% csrf_token %}    
        <input type="text" placeholder = "Enter City Name" id = "city_name">
        <input type="submit" value = "start" id="submit">
        <input type="reset" value = "Stop" id="stop">

    </form>
```

**JS file**

```
$(function(){

    $("#start").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data : { 'city_name' : $("#city_name").val(),
                     'signal' : "True"
                   },

               });
    });

    $("#stop").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data : { 'city_name' : $("#city_name").val(),
                     'signal' : "False"
                   },

               });
    });
});
```

**services.py**

```
def generate_random_temperature(city_name, status):

    city = City.objects.filter(city_name = city_name)

    for data in city:
        status = data.status

    print status
    if status == "True" :
        while(1):
            print randrange(1,51)
            time.sleep(5)   
    elif status == "False" :
        print "Exiting"
```

**views.py**

```
def dashboard(request):

if request.is_ajax():
    status = request.POST['status']
    city_name = request.POST['city_name']

    city = City.objects.filter(city_name = city_name)
    for data in city:
        data.status = status
        data.save()
    generate_random_temperature(city_name, status)


ctx = {}
return render_to_response('dashboard/dashboard.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
True             // When Start button is clicked, service is started
25
13
False           // When Stop button is clicked, it enters the else section, prints Exiting , but then again starts printing numbers. It does not breaks out of the while loop.
Exiting
[23/Aug/2013 05:38:33] "POST /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2363
45
25
26
31
```

Comment: that mean everytime the condition is True , while 1 too mean everytime it meet 1 , so it will print random number until infinity.

Comment: but I added a `break` too, which does not executes(though the flow goes into the else section when condition is "false" which has the break condition)?

Comment: Condition "False" means when stop button is clicked

Comment: did you try to add some exception before in the loop

Comment: check the new solution

Answer (score 0):

You logic/understanding is not correct.

The way you have written the service, when browser sends request to start, it never gets response to that request. In short, the request handler for that request the `dashboard()` view never returns the response. That is because `generate_random_temperature()` never returns when its called with `signal=True`.

You have to think of some different logic to start service and return from the function, may be different thread. And the signal should be shared across threads/process depending upon your deployment (each request runs as cgi which may run as different process/thread in the webserver).

Comment: What? Never returns? I didnt wanted anything to return at first place. Since, I've shown the output , the service does get starts, means it prints the random numbers generated, but it is not able to stop/break out of the loop though it enters the `else` section.

Answer (score 0):

When the first request is made to start the service, that service continues forever. There is no way at all for it to break out of the loop, because `signal` cannot change *within that call to the function*.

A second call will indeed enter the `stop` branch, but that's irrelevant because the original invocation is still continuing.

What you need is some piece of shared data that can be set outside the loop, and checked within it. Perhaps you could use the database: store a 'state' object, and when `stop` is sent set it to 'stop'. Then on every loop of the generator, you'd need to fetch that object from the database, and check its status.

(If you could guarantee that you were running in a single-threaded environment, a global variable would be better here, but a Django deployment is unlikely to be suitable for that.)

Comment: Well , I have 2 questions. `1:)` Why the first service of generating numbers still continuing even after clicking stop button, though a break was provided to get it out of the loop? `2:)`Your idea of saving the state inside the db seems do-able, but I wanted to confirm that whether this kind of method works in a real environment or not?

Comment: But I explained the answer to question 1. That loop will *never* exit because that call never returns. The stop button is *another* call, which returns immediately, but the first one continues.

Comment: I get that , but is there any way to rectify this code, not considering DB solution?

Comment: I tried your DB solution , but the same problem seems to appear again!! Can you please look into it. Thanks

Comment: Check the question again. I've edited with the DB code i tried